# how to login using facebook in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to login using facebook php sdk 5.0 in codeigniter but an error occurs:

> Facebook class not found.

[This is file structure and library file to use faceboojk sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6PBf.png)

Comment: Facebook library is not in some namespace?

Comment: how i don't understand?

Comment: Try this [Login with Facebook using PHP](http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-php/)

Comment: Open Facebook\Facebook.php. Check for namespace on top of file.

Comment: namespace Facebook; this is write there

Comment: @Rafiq not in core php..i m using codeigniter

Comment: Then do `class Fbconnect extends \Facebook\Facebook`

Comment: This works for me [Login with Facebook in CodeIgniter](http://www.codexworld.com/facebook-login-codeigniter/)

Comment: ok..i will try it

Comment: its not showing me user data i think getuser() function not working.after login it take me to again login not showing user data

Comment: But right now you are passed that Facebook class not found? ;)

Comment: yes @Rafiq gave me a link so i was trying that

Comment: can u give me any working code link or attachment to login with fb and getting user info

Comment: @Vini i try class Fbconnect extends \Facebook\Facebook but it gave me this error       A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' not found

Filename: libraries/Facebook.php

Line Number: 133

Backtrace:

Comment: Then you have bigger problem. How did you obtain this library, it looks like it needs autoloader from composer

Comment: i download this library from facebook...

Comment: do u have any working link to login with facebook and get login user data

Comment: From that github?
https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

If yes, you need to use https://getcomposer.org/ to make it work. Or write custom autoloading, but that's probably over your head.

Comment: i already have facebook api files i want working source code link to login using codeigniter

Comment: if u have source code than send me plz

Comment: Ok I'm done. You are not trying to understand what you are doing wrong and fix it, you just want copy and paste everything.

Even if I send you working copy it won't work on your setup because you don't use proper autoloading (and you even don't know how to use classes with namespaces). Go back and learn some basic stuff. I won't do your job for you.

Comment: i try to fix my problem but i don't get any answer..

Comment: if anyone have working code than i will match it with my code and i understand where i do mistake

Comment: @Vini i got the tutorial now i understand what u are saying about composer..thank for suggestion

Answer (score -1):

facebook api does not work on localhost..
[watch this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLolKdIQNXLsyauYFavocoF-3vItlT7ciQ)

Comment: Of course it works. And that video is not even in English.

Comment: than give me link of that tutorial

Comment: i think i was creating live app but for localhost i have to create a test app on facebook

Comment: i have a doubt now can't be get other account information like:-name,profile etc on localhost.who logged in using my app